# How to compare array with position in php?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays and I have to compare two arrays with positions :

```
$mission = array(1,1,0,0,0);
$user = array(1,1,1,0,0);
```

The aim is simple (but bit complex too), I have to check if user match the mission array values positions, above user can take mission, but if user is like

```
$user = array(1,0,0,0,0);
```

he cannot, but in other case if user has (1,1,1,0,0) or (1,1,1,1,0) or (1,1,1,1,0) he can take mission.

Could you help me please ?

Thank you

Comment: So if user's array contains more one's than mission's array, it can take the mission?

Comment: yes, that's it but position is important too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you just need to compare all the corresponding values in the arrays:

```
$can_do_mission = true;
foreach ($mission as $key=>$value) {
    if (0 != $value && $user[$key] < $value) {
        $can_do_mission = false;
    }
}
```